# new mysqli(): how to intercept an 'unable to connect' error?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm doing this *(yes, I'm using wrong connection data, it's to force a connection error )*

```
try {
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db') ;
} catch (Exception $e ) {
    echo "Service unavailable";
    exit (3);
}
```

But PHP is doing this php_warning:

> mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In the example I'm using wrong connection data to force a connection error, but in the real world the database could be down, or the network could be down... etc..

**Question:** Is there a way, *without suppressing warnings,* to intercept a problem with the database connection ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to tell mysqli to throw exceptions:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
     $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db') ;
} catch (Exception $e ) {
     echo "Service unavailable";
     echo "message: " . $e->message;   // not in live code obviously...
     exit;
}
```

Now you will catch the exception and you can take it from there.

Comment: It's a pretty bad idea to show the end user the error message. It's a potential security risk, it's better to log the error to a file and siaplay a generic errror message.

Comment: This does not handle the case where the database does not exist.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Yes it does, why wouldn't it? Note that you'll likely get a "access denied" error in that case.

Comment: @YourCommonSense To illustrate on SO what is happening and what information is available about the exception?

Comment: This is brillient. I have mine set up for the server but I like to default to localhost when I am on a local machine so I was using connect_errno to check if there was a connection error and then going to localhost. This is a much better solution as it doesn't show an error

Answer (score 9):

For PHP 5.2.9+

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error, '. $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

You'll want to set the Report Mode to a strict level as well, just as jeroen suggests, but the code above is still useful for specifically detecting a connection error. The combination of those two approaches is what's recommended in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php#example-1925).

Comment: The @ operator has a lot of problems and should be avoided.  Jeroen has a much better solution.

Comment: This is the right approach.  Unfortunately, this will not correctly report a non-existent database, to which I have provided a solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Check `$connection->connect_error` value.

See the example here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score -3):

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);, as described elsewhere, gives me an error and stops the script immediately.  But this below seems to provide the desired output for me...

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db') ;

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

if($connection->connect_errno)
{
  // Database does not exist, you lack permissions, or some other possible error.
    if(preg_match($connection->connect_error, "Access denied for user"))
    {
        print("Access denied, or database does not exist.");
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }
}
```

Attempting to catch this error with try..catch() will fail.

Comment: There is nothing desirable in telling a site user that they don't have whatever permissions. Your idea on error handling is essentially wrong.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: There is everything desirable in telling a site user about database permissions, if that site user is also a member of the db-admin team.   Your criticism applies equally to the OP's question.

Comment: There is even more nothing desirable in showing to a member of the db-admin team a *fake* error message, which is deliberately artificial and may have nothing in common with the real problem occurred.

Comment: Did you read the OP's post?  "mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) "  That is the error message for a non-existent database or a database without permission.  The print statement is the equivalent of a comment.  I'm demonstrating how the code can work.

Comment: Did you read the OP's post? "*I'm using wrong connection data to force a connection error, but in the real world the database could be down, or the network could be down... etc..*". Access denied is not the only error that can ever occur. There are thousands other errors. Your code will repeat the same message for all of them.

Comment: How would you detect that a database doesn't exist with MySQLi, then?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to check the database existence, report a non-existent database error or handle this error? All three tasks have different solutions.

Comment: I only mentioned the first one, the other two problems you raise are only tangential.  How would you detect, using PHP's MySQLi only, that a database doesn't exist?  My method does the job (no, it's not an entire error-handling module, it's not supposed to be).  Do you have a method?

Comment: using `SHOW DATABASES LIKE database_name` query?

Comment: Looks finally I managed to understand your confusion. It is based on the "*gives me an error and stops the script immediately.*" statement. To handle an exception, in case you have a certain scenario for a certain error, you have to use `try..catch` operator, checking for this particular error, handling it, or - in case the error is something different, re-throwing the exception to let the script die immediately in peace. Example you may find here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly my point.  SHOW DATABASES and new mysqli() give conflicting, different error messages.  try..catch indicates an incorrect error message, which is why I avoided your suggestion, as indicated by OP, and others posting.

Comment: Looks like you are under some delusion caused by whatever confusion. Show tables doesn'give you an error message, as well as try..catch.

Comment: Run this.  Catch block never executes. <?php

 try{
  $test = new mysqli("site","user","password","notadatabase");
  print("Error: " . $test->connect_error . "|");
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 }

?>

Comment: It's not like your code fails like you have a simple syntax error.  It's more like your code fails like you don't even know which conditionals pass or fail and which blocks of code subsequently get executed.