# mysql query from php isnt working but it works in a different php file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a query from my MySQL database here is the code

```
<?php
     $link = new MySQLi('localhost','root','Rrtynt','copy');
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $name = $_POST['id'];
        $profile = 'profile';                
        $thestring = $name.$profile;
       //echo $thestring;

       $result = $link->query("SELECT Email,Name,idauth FROM user WHERE Email = '$name'");
       echo $result;
        }
?>
```

the code for the query

```
$result = $link->query("SELECT Email,Name,idauth FROM user WHERE Email = '$name'");
```

works in a different php script the same exact code but it keeps giving me http 500 error, I'm using this to post from a javascript file

```
$.post("/getfirstfolder.php", { id: value1 }, function (data) {
                            cop = data;
                            console.log("Data: " + data);
                        });
```

if I take out

```
 $result = $link->query("SELECT Email,Name,idauth FROM user WHERE Email = '$name'");
```

and just echo $thestring it works fine, I cant figure out the problem so thank you for your time and your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: try to get error http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you mentioned $thestring, makes me think that perhaps you should be using $thestring as the parameter to the query like this:

```
$result = $link->query("SELECT Email,Name,idauth FROM user WHERE Email = '$thestring'");
```

Comment: no user is the table for that query, it works in another script so I just tried to use it as a template "which doesn't work" but works in a different script, $thstring is the name of the table that I'm eventually going to query when I get working query code

Comment: but $name will work in that query because its an email address "should work"

Comment: Can you capture the error message?  Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15553741/212514

Comment: I tried to catch it but this is all I get in the console HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR): POST - http://localhost:50976/getfirstfolder.php

Comment: I'm getting this error Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object