# Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\wamp64\www\includes\functions.php on line 86

Tags: php

This is my function that is giving errors do not know why it is not executing at all and this if statement is line 86

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time FROM login_attempts WHERE user_id=? AND time > '$valid_attempts'"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have this file to define details of db

```
<?php

define("HOST", "localhost:3311");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "root");    // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "root");    // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "compared");    // The database name.

define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

define("SECURE", FALSE);   
?>
```

And to create connection here this is the file

```
<?php 
include_once "C:/wamp64/www/includes/psl-config.php";

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);       


?>
```

But it keeps giving error

Comment: Probably you have an error during connection. Try to catch it during connection attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553496/new-mysqli-how-to-intercept-an-unable-to-connect-error

Comment: In the previous 85 lines do you assign `$mysqli` anywhere else? You should bind `$valid_attempts` as well.

Comment: Add `var_dump($mysqli); exit;` immediately before your if statement, what do you get? My guess is the instantiation of the mysqli class failed.

Answer (score 0):

Change `'$valid_attempts'` to `?` and use bind params like you used with `i`