# Why isn't this page displaying any error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to learn how to display specific errors when my MySQL queries fail. For example, in the following code, I've deliberately written the **table name** wrong. So instead of displaying any error, the browser simply doesn't load the page. It displays the message **The localhost page is not working**.

To display error, I tried to use `$mysqli->error`, but it's not working. Same is when I change the database name to wrong database to get **connection error**. Is there something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    public $abc;
    public $con;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->servername = 'localhost';
        $this->username = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->dbname = 'dbind';

        $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
        if(!$this->con){
            echo $this->con->error;
        }
        return $con;
    }

    public function insert_data($emp_name, $emp_dept, $emp_salary)
    {
        $this->abc=$this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO tablec1(name, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
        $this->abc->bind_param("ssi", $emp_name, $emp_dept, $emp_salary);
        $this->abc->execute();
    }
}
?>
<?php
$conobj=new Database();
$query=$conobj->insert_data("vvsdf", "vsomeone", 3445);
if(!conobj->abc){
    die($conobj->con->error);
}
?>
```

Comment: You should tell mysqli to throw an exception when something goes wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553496/new-mysqli-how-to-intercept-an-unable-to-connect-error. Then you will have your errors *and* you can catch them if you want.

Comment: Try `$mysqli::connect_error` instead of `error`

Comment: mysqli is deprecated so better to use pdo

Comment: also mysqli is not secured now

Comment: @AammadUllah No it's not.

Comment: @AammadUllah Oh no its not

Comment: @AammadUllah mysqli is not deprecated. Used correctly, it's secure too.

Comment: @AammadUllah This is incorrect

Comment: Just look at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) and see how they test for a connection error, that is probably the right way to do it, right?

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059 . refer this and try to use pdo in the future

Comment: @jeroen Thank you. I think I should read about such things first. Could you please provide me some more links to learn it?

Comment: What more? You add one line and you get a load of information on any mysqli error that occurs. That's it.

Comment: I did [its called the manual](http://php.net/docs.php) and its written in many languages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php     mysqli is deprecated

Comment: @jeroen Okay. But is there any way to know if a particular statement didn't execute? For example, in my code if the `prepare` or `bind` statement didn't execute, how can I know it?

Comment: You should give it a try.

Comment: @AammadUllah **READ**. The OP is using mysql**i** and prepared statements.

Comment: Try what? Could you please explain?

Comment: @AammadUllah : `mysql_*` is depricated not `mysqli_*`

Comment: write ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); inside your constructor at start

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried but it's not working.

Comment: You tried what and its not working????