# Issue with the mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

`mysqli_query` function not working

```
$query=mysqli_query($config,"INSERT into users (username,first_name,last_name,email,password) VALUES('$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pass','$date','0')");");
```

When I echo the SQL query it worked fine but when I tried to insert into database its not doing anything and goes to next line .

I used a submit button like this `$signup = @$_POST['signup'];`

`signup` is the name of the submit button.

Comment: Are you sure the query is complete? It doesn't mention what to insert...

Comment: Insert what? You didnt specify what You want to insert

Comment: it goes like this : $query=mysqli_query($config,"INSERT into users VALUES('$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pass','$date','0')");

Comment: That is still not a complete query. First you set the names of the columns you want to populate, then you insert the values. Something like this: `INSERT INTO users (column1,column2,column3) VALUES ('value1','value2','value3')`. Please read a bit of documentation before asking questions.

Comment: You dont need column names if you want to fill all of them

Comment: You need to add error handling to see what is wrong. For example by having mysqli throw exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15553741/42139

Comment: @David Edit the question and add all the required details (properly formatted) so that others don't have to ask each and every details separately

Comment: @Spidey i edited it

Comment: Check my answer now and make some debug.

Comment: it doesn't have to do anything with @ sign ???

Comment: Delete it,  it cause that errors dont show up

Comment: Read my answer, there may be a problem in your query with `)`

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Informations**

There are two basic syntaxes of INSERT INTO statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

You may not need to specify the column(s) name in the SQL query if you are adding values for **all** the columns of the table.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (value1,value2,value3);
```

**How to check errors**

You can also check your connection if is estabilished or are there any errors with following code:

```
if (!$config) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

Or at the end you can check your query errors with :

```
echo mysqli_error($config);
```

More informations about debugging you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

**Problems in your code**

**1.**
In your code you have too many `)` it should be like follows:

```
$query=mysqli_query($config,"INSERT into users (username,first_name,last_name,email,password) VALUES('$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pass','$date','0');");
```

**2.**
Also you are trying to insert 7 values to 5 tables, there is too much in `VALUES`, or you have wrote too less tables.

**3.**
Delete `@` before your `$_POST` because maybe there is some error, and it cause that it will not show up. More informations can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: Show us what you got in `$config`

Comment: $config=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","site") or die("could not select to database ");

Comment: You can try to paste your query in phpmyadmin and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to fix your query cause you've stated 5 fields and trying to insert 7 values...

So once you know the field names for **"no_clue_what_this_guy_is_called and date"** then you might progress further. Also, please watch your ") as you have too many...

And on another note, please don't use short variable names. It's just painful. It costs nothing to type out "big words". I.E. $un should be $user_name or the like.

So based on your question and bad variable names, you'd want something like...

```
$query = mysqli_query($config, "INSERT into users(
                    username,
                    first_name,
                    last_name,
                    email,
                    password,
                    date,
                    no_clue_what_this_guy_is_called
                    ) VALUES (
                    '$un',
                    '$fn',
                    '$ln',
                    '$em',
                    '$pass',
                    '$date',
                    '0'
                    )");
```

And you only need to quote columns that are varchars/text and the like. Do not use single quotes around integers.

There's more that can be said, but this should get you working on this part of your issue.
I'm not sure what type '0' is defined as in your table.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use like this

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host_name","db_username","db_password","db_name");

$query = "insert into tbl_name(col1,col2,col3) values('$val1','$val2','$val3')";

$insert = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```